# Django and api widget

Tags: django, sqlite, widget

I am relatively new in web development and I needed your help with the following.

I am creating a basic website using Django where a user can manage his portfolio.
Now I was using [this](https://in.tradingview.com/widget/watchlist/) widget from Tradingview.com in [this](https://fiscussolutions.herokuapp.com/Portfolio/) manner.

Now what I wanted to know was if I could somehow store what the user was adding in the watchlist in the database itself and load it when the widget loads next time

Answer (score 0):

Tradingview.com's widget is implemented using an iframe tag on your website, so you want to execute javascript inside the iframe so everytime a user adds to his wishlist you sent an ajax request to your django backend.

but thats not possibles if the widget is from another domain than tradingview.com

> Calling a parent JS function from `iframe` is possible, but only when
>   both the parent and the page loaded in the `iframe` are from same
>   domain i.e. abc.com, and both are using same protocol i.e. both are
>   either on `http://` or `https://`.
>
> The call will fail in below mentioned cases:
>
> 1. Parent page and the iframe page are from different domain.
> 2. They are using different protocols, one is on http:// and other is on https://.
>
> Any workaround to this restriction would be extremely insecure.
>
> For instance, imagine I registered the domain superwinningcontest.com
>   and sent out links to people's emails. When they loaded up the main
>   page, I could hide a few `iframe`s in there and read their Facebook
>   feed, check recent Amazon or PayPal transactions, or--if they used a
>   service that did not implement sufficient security--transfer money out
>   of their accounts. That's why JavaScript is limited to same-domain and
>   same-protocol.

SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663118/4885802

Comment: How about if I let the users add the Ticker symbols as a list and the pass the list in Watchlist